# WebSphere 7 - class loader trace

Tags: websphere

I have just upgraded to WebSphere 7 (from 6.1), and I am having new class loading conflicts which I didn't have before.

I have looked a lot over the internet but couldn't find directions on how:

```
1. How to enable class loading trace.
2. Where does the output go to?
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enable the classloading information you need to go in **application server > server_name > Java and Process Management > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine**, there you will find the verbose classloading option. Enable it and restart the application server.

You should then find the classloading informations in the **native_stderr.log** in the **`<WAS_install_root>/profiles/<profile>/logs/<server>`** directory.

Comment: This doesn't work - I see in the log on startup the same info whether flag is on or not

Comment: Have you also looked in the other files ? From what I see and remember I was the native_stdout.log file which was used to log. see <http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v6/was/6.0/Runtime/WASv6_ClassLoader_PD/player.html>, slide 4.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Olivier.Roger's response (I don't have the permissions to respond inline), the information is in **native_stderr.log**.

(late, but for anyone else who finds this thread like I did)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the [class loader MustGather](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196187) that is used by IBM support when you open a PMR.  Expand the "Collecting data manually" section.